# Socket IO Broadcast from api/router when Heroku Scheduler executes - How?

Tags: angular, express, socket.io

I would like to broadcast or emit to all clients connected through SocketIO whenever a Haroku Scheduler job is executed. I have setup a Heroku Scheduler that executes every 10 min.. It runs a get request that sits in a module called router. The goal it to make updates to client every 10 min. I have tried out with broadcast and emit, but i am fairly new in this game.

I am missing something - maybe SocketIO needs a client request and not a heroku scheduler job to executes, or my server setup is somehow broken. In any case it wont work. Help is needed.

My router

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

const api = require('./routes/api');
const PORT = [3000, process.env.PORT];

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
  }));

app.use(express.json());

//Middleware that attach io to req so that I can use it in router.
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    req.io = io;
    next();
})

app.use('/api', api);

server.listen(PORT[1], function(){
    console.log("app listen on localhost port something" )
});
```

My router (which is executed every 10 min.).

```
router.get('/event/emitEventUpdates', (req, res)=>{
    //Every 10 min. the events on client must be updated
    console.log("i server emitEventUpdates");
    req.io.on('connection', function (socket) {
        socket.emit('message', {type:'new-message', text: "message from server"});
server"});
        res.send({message : "all done from API"})
    })
})
```

My client is an Angular 6 app that makes connection. The Observable looks like this:

```
let observable = new Observable(observer => {
    this.socket.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log("Received message from Websocket Server")
    })
    return () => {
      this.socket.disconnect();
    }
});
```

I would imagine that whenever the observable is active, the console should write something to the console. I can add additional information about it if needed, but I think the problem is server side..

Comment: Could you please try one thing, just to rule it out before suggesting to make socket io service. Instead of running req.io.on.... just run req.io.emit('message', your payload);

Comment: @noitse - how should I then make the connection? Where should I make it?

Comment: Check the answer bellow. If you don't get console.logs on connection, you are doing something wrong off the bat.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot answer since I will try to cover a lot. Comment as much as you can if this is not it, or if you are tracking user states, I can edit the answer and help you.

Javascript is language that gives us the opportunity to break everything in services and classes and individual files, where these files have only specific tasks.

That's why I will suggest first to create an individual socket.io file that handles its core functionality.

```
// socketio.js
let _io;
module.exports.runSocket = (server) => {
   _io = require('socket.io')(server);
   _io.on('connect', (socket) => {
      console.log('New socket connected', socket.id);
      // You will see here if connections are even being run;
      // You can have all kinds of listeners here for connected sockets,
      // Since i dont see that you are tracking anything, i will just leave it as is.
   });
}
module.exports.emitToAll = (type, payload) => {
   // This will emit to all connected sockets
   _io.emit(type, payload);
}
```

Then in your app.js

```
// app.js
const _sio = require('./socketio.js'); 
_sio.runSocket(server);
```

There is no need to send IO to req anymore since it is initiated only once in run socket function;

And in your route

```
const _sio = require('./socketio.js');

router.get('/event/emitEventUpdates', (req, res)=>{ 
        _sio.emitToAll('message', {type:'new-message', text: "message from server"})
        res.send({message : "all done from 
});
```